# angularjs interceptor and responseError return wrong response HTTP code

Tags: angularjs, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors, jwt

I use angularjs 1.5.0 and angular-jwt 0.1.11.

I try use interceptor for catch case when backend return 401 Unauthorized and redirect user to login page.

My interceptor looks like that:

```
import angular from 'angular';

export default angular
    .module('app.factories', [])
    .factory('test_interceptor', function ($q) {
        "ngInject";
        return {
            'responseError': function(rejection) {
                // do something on success
                let status = rejection.status;
                console.log('test_interceptor responseError');
                console.log(rejection);
                console.log(rejection.status);
                return rejection;
            },
        };
    });
```

But when I delete token from local storage and try make request I get error 401 from backend, but rejection status is -1:

[image]

How it looks in network tab:

[image]

What am I doing wrong, why I don't see 401 code?

Comment: Status -1 often means the browser blocked the response because of a CORS problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that once you define the interceptor factory that you register it with the $httpProvider during config stage by pushing it into its interceptors array.

Example using your interceptor:

```
app.config(["$httpProvider", $httpProvider => {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push("test_interceptor");
}]);
```

[Here is a related article for further research](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

[Related docs for your angularjs version](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

Comment: Yes, interceptor registered, i even stop at breakpoint in interceptor, so it works.